# How to structure database for daily event log?

Tags: database, data-structures

I'm storing data which logs whether or not a user has logged their attendance for a given day. Some days are unimportant (holiday, weekend), so those are also stored.

The two requirements are that:

1. Calculating the number of logs and missed logs can be done quickly, and
2. The structure is scallable for whenever new users are added.

Right now it seems like I'm faced with two options for how the data should be stored, each with their own advantages/disadvantages:

**Option 1: Two Tables**

Table `calendar` - Tracks days to be not counted

```
date       | log |
-----------+-----|
2019-01-10 | DNL | // "Do Not Log" - holiday etc.
2019-01-12 | NB  | // "Non-business day"
2019-01-13 | NB  |
```

Table `logs` - Tracks successful attendance logs

```
user_id | date       |
--------+------------|
      1 | 2019-01-08 |
      1 | 2019-01-09 |
      2 | 2019-01-09 |

// It's implied that user #2 missed their log on Jan. 8
```

Advantages:

- Data is efficiently stored.
- Tallying user logs and non-counting days is trivial.

Challenges:

- Knowing how many days were missed is not obvious.

**Option 2: One Table** (What I've tried)

Table `calendar` - Tracks logs and days to be counted and not counted

```
date       | user_id | log  |
2018-01-09 |       1 |    1 | // Counted, logged
2019-01-10 |       1 |  DNL | // Not counted
2019-01-11 |       1 |   NB | // Not counted
2019-01-09 |       2 | NULL | // Counted, missed log
```

Advantages:

- A tally of days missed vs. days logged is trivial (used to calculate an overall percentage). The number of days in the calendar is explicit.

Challenges:

- Adding new entries to the calendar is tricky, in the event that:

  - The calendar grows in length.
  - New users are added.
- Table has gaps (wherever `log` == `NULL`), making traversal slower than Option 1.

My question is this: Is there a way to either use Option 1 and somehow encode the number of missed logs, or is there some other way of storing the data that meets both requirements? I've tried using Option 2, although scaling has become quite a challenge. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: "Some days are unimportant (holiday, weekend), so those are also stored". Do you mean "important"? Where do they "log their attendance"? In another database? You should just be able to run a query on that.

Answer (score 0):

The two table solution looks better to me. Whereas it's not obvious how many days were missed, it's easy enough to compute.

Let's say you want to figure out which days user X missed between `start-date` and `end-date`.

1. Get a list of all the special days between `start-date` and `end-date`.
2. Get a list of all the days the user signed in between `start-date` and `end-date`.
3. Do the following:

   for each day from start-date to end-date
       if day is in special days, continue to next day
       if day is in dates user logged in, continue to next day
       The user didn't log in on this day

You can do it by creating sets for the special days and the days the user logged in, or by having lists sorted by date and running a simple 3-way merge algorithm.

I'm no SQL guru, but I'd be surprised if you can't do that with a single SQL query.